# Undefined reference to *функции из dll*

Tags: c++, ооп, dll

Я получил несколько .dll файлов с простым фреймворком. И в проекте у меня всего два файла.

1) Хедер, где содержаться все объявления функций из dll.
2) Файл, где я хочу вызвать какие-то из этих функций.

1)

```
#pragma once

#if defined(FRAMEWORK_PROJECT)
#define FRAMEWORK_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FRAMEWORK_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
Class Sprite;

FRAMEWORK_API Sprite* createSprite(const char* path);
FRAMEWORK_API void drawSprite(Sprite*, int x, int y);
FRAMEWORK_API void getSpriteSize(Sprite* s, int& w, int &h);
FRAMEWORK_API void destroySprite(Sprite* s);

FRAMEWORK_API void drawTestBackground();

FRAMEWORK_API void getScreenSize(int& w, int &h);

FRAMEWORK_API unsigned int getTickCount();

FRAMEWORK_API void showCursor(bool bShow);

enum class FRKey
{
    RIGHT,
    LEFT,
    DOWN,
    UP,
    COUNT
};

enum class FRMouseButton
{
    LEFT,
    MIDDLE,
    RIGHT,
    COUNT
};

class FRAMEWORK_API Framework
{
public:
            virtual void PreInit(int& width, int& height, bool& fullscreen) = 0;

    virtual bool Init() = 0;

    virtual void Close() = 0;

    virtual bool Tick() = 0;

    // param: xrel, yrel: The relative motion in the X/Y direction 
    // param: x, y : coordinate, relative to window
    virtual void onMouseMove(int x, int y, int xrelative, int yrelative) = 0;

    virtual void onMouseButtonClick(FRMouseButton button, bool isReleased) = 0;

    virtual void onKeyPressed(FRKey k) = 0;

    virtual void onKeyReleased(FRKey k) = 0;

    virtual ~Framework() {};
};
FRAMEWORK_API int run(Framework*);
```

2)

```
#include "Framework.h"

class MyFramework : public Framework {

public:
    virtual bool Tick()
    {
        drawTestBackground();
        return (false);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return run(new MyFramework);
}
```

Но при любом вызове я получаю ошибку undfined reference. Исходников dll у меня нет. 
*Подскажите что не так: ошибка моя, или, возможно, в самых dll?*

Я только начал работать на ОС Windows и впервые столкнулся с DLL, поэтому буду благодарен за любые указания на ошибки.

Компилирую так: g++ frame.lib game.cpp

[image: Примеры ошибки]

Comment: а передавать библиотеку для линковки компилятору через ключик `-l` кто будет?

Comment: Такого рода ошибка возникает, если линковщик не видит кода, то есть реализации вызываемых функций. Заголовки видит, по ним берет функции, пытается прилинковать реализации, а найти не может вот и `undefined reference`

Comment: Товарищ @Fat-Zer, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно компилировать с этим флагом. Пускай у меня есть frame.lib.
Я компилю так: g++ -o game.exe game.cpp -lframe
Но оно не находит мою либу.

Comment: @Laughing_Man, где именно она лежит? в текущем каталоге? и `.lib` — вероятнее всего статическая библиотека, а не разделяемая. Так что скорей всего её следует указать вместе с остальными исходниками/объектниками в опциях компилятора(линкера); через `-l` тоже должно работать, но утверждать не берусь т.к. не знаю особенностей работы линкера под win... А ещё ключик -l обычно нужно указывать до исходников/объектников, в которых используются эти символы (поставь его в начало).

Comment: @Fat-Zer, всё в текущем каталоге и .lib файлы и .dll

Comment: угум... это были скорее риторические вопросы...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну-с, тогда я понятия не имею что делать :D

g++ -lframe game.cpp;
g++ frame.lib game.cpp;

Результата не дают.

Comment: @Laughing_Man, а либа чем была собрана? [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472924/linking-to-msvc-dll-from-mingw) говорят, что если msvc, то с помощью gcc уже не слинкуешь....

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да, таки там. Спасибо.

Comment: Что такое `Class Sprite;` в самом начале заголовочного файла??? Как это вообще компилируется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, что нужно делать в таких кейсах:

1. правильно линковать файлы через флаги -l -L.
2. проверить или файл не был создан через Visual Stduio. Если да, то файл нужно добавить к проекту в Visual Stduio. Просто через командную строку компилиться не будет.